# How to display multiple notification count badge on app icon in Oreo?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm getting the notification in **Oreo** version. But i need to show count badge on app icon. I'm not able to display the count badge.

Function for getting the notification

```
public void sendOnChannel1(View v){
            String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
            String messagge = editTextMessage.getText().toString();
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_1_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_one)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messagge)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                    .setNumber(3)

                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                    .build();


            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

And this function is for create notification channel

```
private void createNotificationChannels() {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                try{
                    NotificationChannel channel1=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1_ID, "Channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");
                    channel1.setShowBadge(true);
                    channel1.canShowBadge();
                    NotificationManager manager=getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

I want to display count badge on app icon. Please Help

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

this isn't depend on you... from the [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setNumber(int)):

> Sets the number of items this notification represents. May be displayed as a badge count **for Launchers that support badging**.

so if user is using Launcher without badging support he won't get any dot, not mentioning number... personally I'm using (default) Launcher on my device, which supports only dot, no number at all